# how to solve "that link is dead" error in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a complete directed weighted graph. Also, I have a max-links list where the maximum out-link of all turtles are in there. But sometimes two turtles give opposite links as their maximum out-links such as link (2 3) and link (3 2). I've managed to delete the link with the lower value and update the list

```
  ask turtles
  [
      set x max-one-of my-out-links [trust]
      set y one-of my-in-links
  ]
          ask links
      [
      set test1  [[x] of end1] of self
      set test2  [[y] of end2] of self
          foreach max-links
          [
            the-links -> ask the-links
            [
              if  [[who] of end1 ] of test1 = [[who] of end2] of test2
                  and [[who] of end2] of test1 = [[who] of end1] of test2
              [
                set max-links sort-on [(- label)] link-set [max-one-of my-out-links [label]] of turtles
                ifelse  [trust] of [x] of end1 < [trust] of [x] of end2
                [ask [x] of end1 [die]]
                [ask [x] of end2 [die]]
                if one-of max-links = nobody
                [set max-links sort-on [(- label)] link-set [max-one-of my-out-links [label]] of turtles]
                show max-links
              ]
            ]
            set max-links sort-on [(- label)] link-set [max-one-of my-out-links [label]] of turtles
          ]
```

However, when the if turns out true, it does indeed delete the link with the lower value but it gives the error of "that link is dead"
and shows max-links with a nobody in the list:

> [(link 0 5) nobody (link 4 5) (link 2 4) (link 1 0) (link 3 2)]

I tried to get rid of the nobody with this section:

```
if one-of max-links = nobody
[set max-links sort-on [(- label)] link-set [max-one-of my-out-links [label]] of turtles]
show max-links
```

but it has no effect.

Comment: You can't solve the "link is dead" error (as asked in your title) - you want it to die, so there's nothing to solve. If what you're actually asking is how to remove something from a list, look up `filter` in the NetLogo dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

When an agent or link dies, it is removed from any turtle-set or link-set in which contained it, but references to the now dead link in lists or other variables are set to `nobody`.  So, your code is doing exactly what one would expect.  If you want to remove it from the list, then JenB's suggestion is the way to go.  If you want to delete dead links from `max-links`, then

```
set max-links filter is-link? max-links
```

'nobody' is not a link, so it will be filtered out.  Then, your `if` should work.